# What is the limit of modal view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I realize that I can present modal view hierarchically.
When present a several modal views by using the selector listed below

> presentModalViewController: animated:

(The hierarchy of the structure should be something like A->B->C->D->F........)

Assuming I create a lot of modal views with considerable content in each of them.
How could I know if I reach the limit of the memory? If the application is into the 'Suspend' state and receive a low memory warning.

What will happen if the user relaunch the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to dispose of one modal view controller and put up another one is to animate only the last one:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:controllerB
   animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no limit of modal views (I'm not aware of it) - just memory. And you can't check if you have enough memory or not. System will tell you when you reach your limit with memory warning.

What do you mean with relaunch? Suspend & resume? If yes, nothing. Kill & fresh start? No modal views unless you present them again.

The best way to accomplish this task is to release all objects that can be recreated in A when you do display B. Release in B when you do display in C and so on. But it depends on what do you want to display in them (in other words, amount of memory used by each view controller).

Comment: I do want to avoid the memory leak. If I display B and don't need A any more. How can I release A?

Comment: Dismiss A and present B. A will be released.

Comment: How can I do that exactly? Like "[self presentModalViewController:B animated:YES]; [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];" ?

Comment: No, first dismiss A and in completion block of dismissal present B. BTW why this way? Isn't UINavigationController better?